# Using Configuration files in multi-module maven project

Tags: java, maven, maven-3, maven-plugin, maven-module

I am working on multi-module maven project (newbe to multi-module maven projects).

I have **Module A** with the directory structure **/ModuleA/ConfigFiles/config.properties**.

And **Module B** which uses the **Module A** using maven dependency.

Now **Module A** source file retrieves the config file as

```
String configFile = System.getProperty("user.dir")+"\\ConfigFiles\\config.properties";
```

So when I call the **Module A** function from **Module B** , it is using **Module B** local project directory instead of **Module A**'s project directory.

Is there any solution/workaround to this in multi-module project ?

Comment: Why are you referencing the config file based on your src directory? What happens to it when you package your project?

Comment: I am not sure, since I am new to this one. I created one maven module and it needs config file of its own, which is used only by that module. So I used its base directory to store the config file. 
And the other module which is inheriting it (as Maven dependency) is calling those functions.
Since I am calling **"user.dir"** ,  jvm is accessing the inherited module base folder instead of base module directory.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think that using resources mechanics here is the best approach. Just place your config file somewhere in `src/main/resources` directory of **Module A**. Next change your code that read config file respectively ([here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20389255/reading-a-resource-file-from-within-jar) is some information how to read from resource files).

After that change you will read config from classpath, not from exact directory and there will be no difference whether you call your function from **Module A** or **Module B**.